# How to run a python script 24/7 or for a time frame on firebase or any other platform

Tags: python, firebase

After researching a bit, I had to ask here.

**Aim** :- I need to run a python script for let's say 6 hours "daily" and whenever some condition gets satisfied in the script during that time, it should send an automatic notification to some users.

I was hoping we can do this on firebase but couldn't find anything similar to it.
Why Firebase ? Because in firebase I could send notification to specific users.

I actually created a kivy mobile app but that didn't work so yeah, if anybody has some experience or have done such kind of project I need your help please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about using crontab? Run the script periodically

Comment: on Linux I would use `cron` to execute it every few minutes.

Comment: @AliHakimTaşkıran what If I want to deploy it to any server, like firebase  and run there every day for 6 hours, is it possible ?

Comment: @dev1ce Connect to server by ssh and run the crontab in the server. You can run the script in various time periods